# Point to Point Protocol

Tags: ppp

I have recently been working on Point to Point Protocol. My understanding is that it is a peer to peer link layer protocol which provides packet data connection over unconventional physical medium. So on both the peers the PPP runs at the link layer.

My weird doubt is that is there any PPP implementations which run at application layer and provide tunneling there itself without going down to Internet layer. I mean can I set up a PPP link without having an IP for either end of the peer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,i think it should work, as it is layer 2 protocol.
PPP also tunnels Internet Protocol (IP) or other network Layer 3 data between two directly connected nodes over a physical connection, or over a direct link. Since IP and Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) do not support point-to-point connections, the use of PPP can enable them over Ethernet and other physical media.

In terms of the OSI model, PPP provides Layer 2, or data-link, service. PPP is a full-duplex protocol that can be used on a variety of physical media.